# Keep transaction within Spring Integration flow

Tags: transactions, spring-integration

Inboud gateway:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway   id="inbound.gateway"
                            request-channel="transactional.channel.input"
                            reply-channel="channel.output"
                            error-channel="channel.error"
                            request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

Advice definition:

```
<tx:advice id="advice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="send" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="MyClassException"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Advice config:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="advice" pointcut="bean(transactional.channel.input)"/>
</aop:config>
```

Chain that needs to be transactional:

```
<int:chain input-channel="transactional.channel.input" output-channel="non.transactional.channel.input>
    <int:service-activator ref="v1.registerUser.service" method="registerUser"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="v1.saveObject.service" method="saveObject"/>
</int:chain>
```

Chain that needs the transaction to be executed previously to get the object id generated in last transational chain step:

```
<int:chain input-channel="non.transactional.channel.input" output-channel="channel.output">
    <int:service-activator  ref="v1.getObjectId.service" method="getObjectId"/>
    <int:object-to-json-transformer/>
</int:chain>
```

Having this simplified context, when I access to the id in getObjectId service, the transaction has not been executed.

So the transaction seems to be commited at inbound-gateway output level.

Comment: It depends on how your flow starts - what do you have upstream of `v1.getEvent.channel.input` ?

Comment: I have an inbound-gateway connected to one chain and this one has `v1.getEvent.channel.input` as output-channel so: `(inbound-gateway)` -> `(chain)` -> `(code I have posted)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One more amazing trick without writing any Java code:

```
<channel id="input"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="bean(input)"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
     <tx:method name="send"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

With this all your direct singlethreaded message flow will be wrapped to the TX on the message sending to the channel **input**

Comment: Hi Artem. Returning to this topic to make sure. I am using this approach with an chain input channel so the transaction commit will be made when the chain is finished, right? Because I realized and object id is being null when I ask for it after persist it but it is stored correct in DB.

Comment: Right, because all others `send` for underlying chain's channels are done within thread of your `input` channel.

Comment: Hi Artem, I have change the question to show you mi current simplified context because the transaction is not being executed when the chain finishes (I have confirm it with ecliselink FINE log).

Comment: Antonio, it whould be better, if you start new question. But looks like you misunderstood my answer. Transaction is bounded to the thread around method invocation. In you case it is 'send()' of 'transactional.channel.input' bean. But if all other channels are **direct** in the downstream flow, so all other 'send' and 'handleMessage' will be within that transaction. To achieve you requirement for TX commit, you make your 'non.transactional.channel.input' as executor channel or queue. Hope it is clear

Comment: I have edit it because I think other people with situations related to this one can see the point easiest with the new example...sorry anyway. By the way, I have found that object id null it was a problem related to merge method so it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 4):

If it's a MessagingGateway injected into your code, you can simply start your transaction at the gateway and, since all channels are direct, the entire flow will run in the same transaction. Simply annotate your gateway method with `@Transactional` and add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` or `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your context (and a transaction manager).

Or you can start your transaction even earlier if you want other stuff in the transaction...

```
@Transactional
public void foo() {
    ...
    Object reply = myGateway.exchange(Object foo);
    ...
}
```

Just be sure to invoke `foo()` from another bean so that the class containing `foo()` is wrapped in a transaction proxy (by @EnableTransactionManagement or `<tx:annotation-driven/>`).

If it's a gateway such as an http inbound gateway, add an `@Transaction`al gateway after the inbound gateway to start the transaction. (Add a service-activator that `ref`s a `<gateway/>` that exchanges `Message<?>` and is annotated with `@Transactional`).

Comment: Thanks for responding Gary! I have finally choose the Artem solution but thanks anyway :)