# Cannot remove a JPA entity using Spring Integration

Tags: jpa, spring-integration

When I try to remove an entity using Outbound Channel Adapter I always get removing a detached instance exception.
I know that an entity should be retrieved and deleted in the same transaction to avoid this exception, but how can I achieve it with Spring Integration?

To demonstrate the problem I modified [the JPA sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jpa):

PersonService.java

```
public interface PersonService {
    ...
    void deletePerson(Person person);
}
```

Main.java

```
private static void deletePerson(final PersonService service) {
    final List<Person> people = service.findPeople();
    Person p1 = people.get(0);
    service.deletePerson(p1);
}
```

spring-integration-context.xml

```
<int:gateway id="personService"
service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.jpa.service.PersonService"
    default-request-timeout="5000" default-reply-timeout="5000">
    <int:method name="createPerson" request-channel="createPersonRequestChannel"/>
    <int:method name="findPeople"   request-channel="listPeopleRequestChannel"/>
    <int:method name="deletePerson" request-channel="deletePersonChannel"/>
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="deletePersonChannel"/>

<int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"
channel="deletePersonChannel" persist-mode="DELETE" >
    <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

When I call deletePerson I get the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Removing a detached instance
>   org.springframework.integration.samples.jpa.Person#1001

**UPDATE:**

Apparently I should've chosen a sample closer to my actual project, because here you can just create a new transaction programmatically and wrap both retrieve and delete function calls in it, as Artem did.

In my project I have a transformer connected to an outbound-channel-adapter. The transformer retrieves an entity and the outbound-channel-adapter removes it. How can I get the transformer and the outbound-channel-adapter to use the same transaction in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it worked you should wrap all operations in the `deletePerson` to transaction, e.g.

```
private static void deletePerson(final PersonService service) {
         new new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager)
       .execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {

            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                 final List<Person> people = service.findPeople();
                 Person p1 = people.get(0);
                 service.deletePerson(p1);

            }
        });
}
```

In this case you should somehow provide to your method **transactionManager** bean too.

UPDATE:

I shown you a sample for use-case in the original question.
Now re. `<transformer>` -> `<jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>`.
In this you should understand where your message flow is started:

1. If it is `<inbound-channel-adapter>` with poller, so just make the `<poller>` `<transactional>`
2. If it `<gateway>`, who call `<transformer>`, so it's just enough to mark gateway's method with `@Transactional`
3. Here is one more **transactional advice** trick: [Keep transaction within Spring Integration flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901510/keep-transaction-within-spring-integration-flow/18914424#18914424)

In all cases you should get rid of `<transactional>` from your `<jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>`

Comment: Thanks Artem, it worked, but is there some way to do it via xml?

Comment: Thanks again, #3 helped me. The thing about #1 and #2 is I don't want to make the whole flow transactional. In my case the flow starts in a tcp-inbound-channel-adapter. Before the transformer I have a router which decides which jpa operation to perform. If it decides to delete, it sends a message to the transformer, and only it transforms a payload into an entity and sends it to the jpa outbound-channel-adapter for a deletion.