# using gateway for starting transaction

Tags: spring-integration

I have been following previous answers that talk about inserting  gateway / service-activator to start a new transaction mid way in SI processing. I have tried below code but for some reason it does not work, if you could point to error in this configuration please.

All the threads seems to be waiting for something to happen and the sp outbound gateway is not invoked, but i cant figure out what.

The idea here is to process each task produced by splitter in a thread pool under a  new transaction.

```
<int:splitter...output-channel="taskChannel"/>
<int:channel id="taskChannel">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>               
</int:channel>       
<int:gateway id="txGw"  service-interface="com.some.test.StartTransactionalGateway"
    default-request-channel="taskChannel" default-reply-channel="individualTask">                               
    </int:gateway>      
<int:service-activator ref="txGw" 
            input-channel="taskChannel"
            output-channel="individualTask" 
            method="startTx"
            auto-startup="true">
</int:service-activator>            

<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway ...request-channel="individualTask" .....

interface StartTransactionalGateway {
     @Transactional 
     Message<?> startTx(Message<?> m);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default-request-channel="taskChannel"` the gateway is sending messages to itself.

You can't mix channels in the subflow with the main channels. You need something like...

```
<int:splitter...output-channel="taskChannel"/>

<int:channel id="taskChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>               
</int:channel>       

<int:service-activator ref="txGw" 
        input-channel="taskChannel"
        output-channel="whereWeWantTheResultsToGo" 
        method="startTx"
        reply-timeout="0"
        auto-startup="true" />

<int:gateway id="txGw"  service-interface="com.some.test.StartTransactionalGateway"
    default-request-channel="toStoredProc" />                               

<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway ...request-channel="toStoredProd" .....
```

You don't need a `default-reply-channel`; simply omit the `reply-channel` on the stored proc gateway and the reply will automatically go back.

Comment: Thanks, Gary, it does work as you suggested however the transaction gets committed as son as SP call returns, i need to now somehow bring rest of the processing under it.

Comment: The commit happens when the thread returns to the gateway so everything you want within the scope of the tx must happen downstream of the gateway. Chain the components - stored proc `reply-channel` connects to the next component, etc. Omit the `reply-channel` or `output-channel` on the __last__ component and the tx will then commit. Or, simply put everything within a `<chain/>`, with no `output-channel`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I tried the former option, it works. Since i do not have any return (it ends on outbound adapter) at the end of this processing so i changed the gateway interface to void and it seems to work as i need it to be. I will try the later option too.

Comment: You can also set `reply-timeout="0"` on the gateway; that way you can use the same gateway for subflows that __do__ return a reply. The reply timer isn't started until the thread returns to the gateway so it's a no-op when there's no reply.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these details!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, Don't forget that you can mark something `transactional` not only using `@Transactional` annotation. There is `<tx:advice>` for the XML declaration.

If you need to wrap to the TX just only that `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>`, there is `<request-handler-advice>` sub-element to wrap the `handleRequestMessage` of the underlying component to any `Advice`:

```
<int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
    <tx:advice>
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
</int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

From other side your code can not work, because `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>` may not return result. The procedure is `one-way`. But the `<gateway>` interface is `request-reply`.

**UPDATE**

See my answer here [Keep transaction within Spring Integration flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901510/keep-transaction-within-spring-integration-flow). It is another trick how to make down-stream flow transactional.

With `<gateway>` you should be sure that your transactional subflow returns to the `replyChannel` in the end. Or... Make your gateway's method as `void` to achieve one-way behaviour.

Comment: Good point; you really only need a tx gateway in the flow if you want to invoke multiple endpoints in the same transaction.

Comment: Thanks good to know this. But i do have subsequent processing that is going on, SP call is just first step to get more data about the task and than processing starts and finally send a JMS Message.  After that i have another db call and finally commit transaction to signal everything went fine else rollback.

Comment: Thanks Artem, taking cue from your answers, i am attempting to start a new transaction on taskExecutor thread, but for some reason it does not start a transaction <aop:config>
     <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="bean(taskExecutor)"/>
 </aop:config>

 <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
     <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="*"/>
     </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>   , any reason why it would not work?

Comment: That's correct, because `Executor.execute` starts a new `Thread` (roughly) and, of course, your TX on `execute` Thread won't be visible from the separate Thread.