# Transaction support with asyc channel( executor channel)

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-integration

I read data from a Q and pass to executor channel to process. No the transaction scope with main thread will not work. How can i can create a  transaction  from executor channel which has multiple direct channels downstream.
Here is the config

```
Read data from some Queue ( gateway)
<int:channel id="mainChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel1"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel2"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel3"/>
      
</int:interceptors>
    </int:channel> 
   <int:channel id="channel1">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec1" />
   </int:channel>
  <int:channel id="channel2">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec2" />
  </int:channel>
   <int:channel id="channel3">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec3" />
  </int:channel>

 <int:chain id="id" input-channel="Channel1">

        
        <int:header-value-router header-name="headerName">
            <int:mapping value="Header1" channel="Channel4"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header2" channel="Channel5"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header3" channel="Channel6"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header4" channel="Channel7"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header5" channel="Channel8"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header6" channel="Channel9"/>
        </int:header-value-router>
    
    </int:chain>
```

So what Channel4-Channel9( all direct channel) does store the data in DB based on some business logic.
requirement is wrap the flow from channel1 to Channel4-Channel9 in single transaction. I tried to find online but couldn't anything.

**EDIT**
Here is what i am doing now

```
Read data from some Queue ( gateway)
<int:channel id="mainChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel1"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel2"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel3"/>      
</int:interceptors>
    </int:channel> 
   <int:channel id="channel1">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec1" />
   </int:channel>
  <int:channel id="channel2">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec2" />
  </int:channel>
   <int:channel id="channel3">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec3" />
  </int:channel>

 <int:chain id="id" input-channel="Channel1">
   <int:service-activator ref="someRef" method="name1">
        <ref bean="txAdvice" />
    </int:service-activator>    
        <int:header-value-router header-name="headerName">
            <int:mapping value="Header1" channel="Channel4"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header2" channel="Channel5"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header3" channel="Channel6"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header4" channel="Channel7"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header5" channel="Channel8"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header6" channel="Channel9"/>
        </int:header-value-router>
           <bean id="transactionManager"  
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>


    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" >
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    </int:chain>
```

Channel4,Channel5 ...Channel9 they all do insert in DB. what i want if any of insert fail transaction should be rolled back.
Still its not rolling back transaction if one of the DB insert fail.

EDIT 3

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" >
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="send" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
        </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>
<aop:config>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="bean(Channel1)"/></aop:config>
```

***EDIT 4 [Solved Config]***

```
<int:channel id="mainChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel1"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel2"/>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel3"/>
</int:interceptors>

    <int:service-activator ref="gatewayID" method = "sendToDB"   input-channel="channel1"/>

    <int:gateway id="gatewayID" service- 
        interface="com.*.*.*.TransactionalGateway"  error- 
         channel="errorChannel" default-request-channel="OutChannel"/>

<int:chain id="id" input-channel="OutChannel">
        <int:header-value-router header-name="headerName">
            <int:mapping value="Header1" channel="Channel4"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header2" channel="Channel5"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header3" channel="Channel6"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header4" channel="Channel7"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header5" channel="Channel8"/>
            <int:mapping value="Header6" channel="Channel9"/>
        </int:header-value-router>

    </int:chain>

public interface TransactionalGateway {

    @Transactional
    void sendToDB(Message<?> m);
```

***ERROR***

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#10': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#2' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#2': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Void] for method match: [public final java.lang.Class[] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.getProxiedInterfaces(), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.setTargetSource(org.springframework.aop.TargetSource), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.setPreFiltered(boolean), public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.removeAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.removeAdvisor(int) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException, public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.isInterfaceProxied(java.lang.Class), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.addAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:738)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at com.citi.loads.framework.StartLoadsApp.lambda$loadContexts$4(StartLoadsApp.java:133)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.forEach(HashMap.java:933)
    at com.citi.loads.framework.StartLoadsApp.loadContexts(StartLoadsApp.java:129)
    at com.citi.loads.framework.StartLoadsApp.runWithFramework(StartLoadsApp.java:109)
    at com.citi.loads.framework.StartLoadsApp.main(StartLoadsApp.java:33)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#2': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Void] for method match: [public final java.lang.Class[] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.getProxiedInterfaces(), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.setTargetSource(org.springframework.aop.TargetSource), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.setPreFiltered(boolean), public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.removeAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.removeAdvisor(int) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException, public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.isInterfaceProxied(java.lang.Class), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.addAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1646)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Void] for method match: [public final java.lang.Class[] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.getProxiedInterfaces(), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.setTargetSource(org.springframework.aop.TargetSource), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.setPreFiltered(boolean), public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.removeAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.removeAdvisor(int) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException, public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.isInterfaceProxied(java.lang.Class), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.addAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:113)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:499)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:226)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.<init>(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:37)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.createMethodInvokingHandler(ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandler(AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:117)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction is just tied to a thread boundaries, so you can't start a transaction sending a message to that executor channel and expect it to be expanded to the subscriber of that channel on the other side, which is going to be indeed a different thread.

However if you point is slightly different (not clear from your question), and you really expect a transaction be be started with your `chain` when it consumes a message and dispatches it to one or more of those channels in the router, then it is possible via `<int:request-handler-advice-chain>` and nested `<bean>` configuration for the `TransactionHandleMessageAdvice`.

See more info about transactions in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html#transactions

See also this my old answer: [Keep transaction within Spring Integration flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901510/keep-transaction-within-spring-integration-flow/18914424#18914424)

Comment: 'However if you point is slightly different (not clear from your question), and you really expect a transaction be be started with your chain when it consumes a message and dispatches it to one or more of those channels in the router, then it is possible via <int:request-handler-advice-chain> and nested <bean> configuration for the TransactionHandleMessageAdvice. thats what i want but i cant use <int:request-handler-advice-chain> inside chain?

Comment: But you can in the first member of the `chain`. The chain by itself does nothing: just calls the first member which will reply to the next and so on. Starting TX from the first will really make the whole chain transactional.

Comment: Thanks Artem for help, i  have edit my original post just showing what did, still its not working, am i missing anything?

Comment: Right. You didn't get me. You have to use that special `TransactionHandleMessageAdvice` instead of standard `<tx:advice>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#tx-handle-message-advice. The standard one wraps into a transaction only a `handleRequestMessage()` phase, but you need the whole `handleMessage()` to be able to propagate transaction downstream to all the rest of flow in the same thread. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#tx-handle-message-advice

Comment: This says it supports from version 5.0 but i m using 4.3, will it work for lower version?

Comment: Well, for that case see my answer in other similar question. I posted a link in the answer.

Comment: Posted my config in EDIT 3, i am following same approach as you mentioned in answer, still it not working. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this?

Comment: OK. I'll take it back: it is not going to work because your `Channel1` is an `ExecutorChannel` I believe. I assume you have tried to edit an original code somehow in the question, so you have now a `channel1` and `Channel1` definitions, which in real life are going to be different instances anyway.

Comment: If you have to stick with a ` <int:dispatcher task-executor="">` for your channels and can't upgrade, then consider to apply that `<tx:advice>` for the `handleMessage` method of the pointcut="bean(id.handler)". Although I believe you have a different `id` for that `<chain>` in your project...

Comment: Another way to achieve transactions is to use an <int:gateway> with a `@Transactional` on gateway method. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway

Comment: i have tried '<tx:advice> for the handleMessage' with "bean(id.handler) with my chain ID  its not working AND  <int:gateway> with a @Transactional i cant ref gateway from chain. So both options seems not working. Might be i need to handle rollback manually. For second option this is similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889780/using-gateway-for-starting-transaction

Comment: The gateway must work. You just need to place a service activator for your `channel1` and point in the `ref` to that `@Transactional` gateway method. That method should send a message into an input channel of the chain. The whole send from the gateway is going to be transactional

Comment: Seems still not working ,I have posted config in EDIT 4 in question. Is there something missing?

Comment: Yeah... I forgot that it doesn't work automatically with XML. Consider to add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` into your config.

Comment: after adding <tx:annotation-driven/> getting this ( not full err)sun.proxy.$Proxy46.setPreFiltered(boolean), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.addAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException, public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.removeAdvisor(int) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException, public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.isInterfaceProxied(java.lang.Class), public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.addAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException]

Comment: So, that confirms that `@Transactional` work. Please, edit your question to show the whole stack trace. Those AOP packages not enough to identify the problem (if that)

Comment: `Found ambiguous parameter type` - you have to say explicitly for your `service-activator` on that gateway which method you'd like to call. In your case it is probably like this: `<int:service-activator ref="gatewayID" method="sendToDB"  input-channel="channel1"/>`. Since your `TransactionalGateway` is proxied with a transaction it is enhanced at runtime with extra interfaces and  therefore a service activator factory must iterate several unrelated methods.

Comment: i am able to run now, it process first message and when reads next message it get stuck where it send message to channel1 , when it stuck it doesn't commit as soon as I  stop the application it commit. Not sure what is missing now. If i remove the code i what i added for transaction then it work fine. I really apricate your help and time.

Comment: As I said in one of my comments: your gateway method must be `void`. Otherwise the gateway call waits for a reply which apparently is not going to happen in your downstream flow.

Comment: I change method to void it works but  its not rolling back. might be need to looks something else

Comment: Better to debug what is going on with your exception and why that `@Transactional` does not rollback...

Comment: Thanks Artem, its working fine.  i will accept your answer now, Also will update the question with correct config to help others.