# Outbound channel adapters in the same transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a scenario where two jms outbound-channel-adapters read from a pub-sub channel and I would like them to participate in a transaction. In other words I would like to write the message to both of them or to none. Even though I set the session-transacted to true, that doesn't seem to happen. Here is what my configuration looks like:

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="test.pubsub" ignore-failures="false" ></int:publish-subscribe-channel>



        <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="test.pubsub" order="1" destination-name="${outbound.queue}" session-transacted="true"
             connection-factory="${connection.factory}"></jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

        <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOutputMirror" session-transacted="true"
                    destination-name="${outbound.queue.mirror}"
                    connection-factory="${connection.factory}"
                     channel="test.pubsub" order="2">
        </jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

They both get their connection from a CachingConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 2):

The `session-transaction` doesn't help you there:

```
/**
 * Set the transaction mode that is used when creating a JMS {@link Session}.
 * Default is "false".
 * <p>Note that within a JTA transaction, the parameters passed to
 * {@code create(Queue/Topic)Session(boolean transacted, int acknowledgeMode)}
 * method are not taken into account. Depending on the Java EE transaction context,
 * the container makes its own decisions on these values. Analogously, these
 * parameters are not taken into account within a locally managed transaction
 * either, since the accessor operates on an existing JMS Session in this case.
 * <p>Setting this flag to "true" will use a short local JMS transaction
 * when running outside of a managed transaction, and a synchronized local
 * JMS transaction in case of a managed transaction (other than an XA
 * transaction) being present. This has the effect of a local JMS
 * transaction being managed alongside the main transaction (which might
 * be a native JDBC transaction), with the JMS transaction committing
 * right after the main transaction.
 * @see javax.jms.Connection#createSession(boolean, int)
 */
public void setSessionTransacted(boolean sessionTransacted) {
    this.sessionTransacted = sessionTransacted;
}
```

If your invocation to both of them isn't wrapped to the TX. Since you are lucky and invoke both adapters in the same thread, only what you need to wrap the message sending to the `test.pubsub` into the TX. e.g. some `@Transactional` `@Gateway` in front of that channel. Or any other possible `<tx:advice>` hooks. You even can consider this solution: [Keep transaction within Spring Integration flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901510/keep-transaction-within-spring-integration-flow/18914424#18914424)

Comment: Just for my understanding: the issue is not that the components in my flow cannot share the transaction but that I need to specify what the boundry of the transaction is. For every flow, Spring won't just start a transaction at the "begining"

Comment: M-m-m. Spring doesn't start transaction if you didn't say that. All what you know about `sessionTransacted` is just up to the local TX in the JMS session for particular invocation. The global transaction must be controlled by you upstream, before those two JMS invocations.